# no console after using :wq in vim

Tags: vim, serial-port, beagleboneblack

When I type :wq in vim, the window freezes and I do not end up in my terminal.
Typing is still accepted, since I can type reboot and kernel messages appear and the system reboots.

When I am stuck, running vim again and quitting it with just :q, the terminal appears again. Vim just gets stuck when using :wq (using :w or :q work as expected)

The system is a beagle bone black with a custom debian and alpine, this happens when using the serial interface (screen for emulator).

```
root@bbb:~# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled May 04 2023 10:24:44)
```

for $TERM, both vt220 (default) and konsole-256color have this behavior.

Using ssh works just fine.

Comment: If commands are accepted try `<Enter>reset<Enter>clear<Enter>` (`<Enter>` is the Enter/Return key). Try `stty sane`.

Comment: Use the issue tracker.